# DISTINCT clause in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Recently i found that SQLite don't support `DISTINCT ON()` clause that seems postgresql-specific. For exeample, if i have table `t` with columns `a` and `b`. And i want to select all items with distinct `b`. Is the following query the only one and correct way to do so in SQLite?

```
select * from t where b in (select distinct b from t)
```

Sample data:

```
a | b
__|__
1   5
2   5
3   6
4   6
```

What i expect in return:

```
a | b
__|__
1   5
3   6
```

Comment: That query will always return all rows from t, since every b in t is part of (select distinct b from t).  Maybe you can clarify a bit more what you are trying to do, and provide some sample data and expected results?

Comment: Unless you explain why `(1,5)` is in your expected result set while `(2,5)` isn't (and why it is exactly this way, and not the other way around), this will be hard to answer.

Comment: Any constrait will do. Minimum, maximum etc. Assumed that real query will need additional columns on DISTINCT only if such data has meaning - for example, it's additional columns are same for same DISTINCT columns.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT MIN(t.a) AS A,
         t.b
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.b
```

Answer (score 12):

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM t GROUP BY b;
2|5
4|6
(for each b: one (unpredictable) value of a)

sqlite> SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY a DESC) GROUP BY b;
1|5
3|6
(for each b: the row with min a)

sqlite> SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY a ASC) GROUP BY b;
2|5
4|6
(for each b: the row with max a)
```

Comment: Actually, I think that "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY a DESC) GROUP BY b;" returns for each b: the row with max a