# GROUP BY with MIN on multiple JOINS tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite and I have a problem with making correct query request in following scenario:

I have four tables, let's call them `t.a`, `t.b`, `t.c`, `t.d`

`t.c` is in multiple to one relation with `t.d`, so `t.c` has column called `parent_id_d`

`t.a` and `t.c` are in multiple to multiple relation with each other so I created junction table called `t.b` to link them to each other.

Now I want to make query request that returns joined rows from `t.a` and `t.d` where each row should have distinct entries in `id_a` column from table `t.a` and `id_d` column from table `t.d` (or `parent_id` column from `t.c`, its the same), generally something like `DISTINCT id_a, id_d` but I want all rows from that table returned so I probably should use `GROUP BY` with `MIN` or `MAX` as stated in this answer [DISTINCT clause in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038575/distinct-clause-in-sqlite) But I can't get it working

Comment: could you show some sample data, the query you have so far, the results it gives, and the results you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to resolve it with this query:

SELECT * FROM `t_a` INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `id_parent_a`, `id_parent_d` FROM `t_b` INNER JOIN `t_c` ON `id_parent_c`= `ic_c`) ON `id_a` = `id_parent_a` INNER JOIN `t_d` ON `id_parent_d`  = `id_d`

where:

1. `id_parent_a` is column in `t_b` with foreign key from `t_a`
2. `id_parent_c` is column in `t_b` with foreign key from `t_c`
3. `id_parent_d` is column in `t_c` with foreign key from `t_d`